# Explain why this augmented matrix is consistent for all h?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm attempting to study for an exam tomorrow and for the life of me, cannot figure out why this matrix is consistent for all h (instead of being only consistent for h=10).

The matrix is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\ 
5 & h & -20
\end{bmatrix}$

I've row reduced it to the form:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\ 
0 & -10+h & 0
\end{bmatrix}

but the reasoning eludes me, could someone explain?

Comment: Ah, typo - but yes, there is actually a zero where that 5 should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were able to see that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\ 
5 & h & -20
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\ 
0 & -10+h & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but what does this really mean? To get a better grasp of the situation, it might help you to look at the matrices in terms of what they *actually* represent, i.e. a system of two linear equations. The right-hand matrix you obtained by a row reduction represents the following linear equations (top row and bottom row, respectively):
$$
x_1 +2x_2 = -4\tag{1}
$$
and 
$$
0x_1+(-10+h)x_2 = 0.\tag{2}
$$
When $h=10$, we see that $(2)$ amounts to 
$$
0x_1+0x_2=0,
$$
and this is obviously true for all values of $x_1$ and $x_2$, and thus the system is consistent when $h=10$. What if $h\neq 10$ though? Can the system still be consistent?

If $h\neq 10$, then we have $h-10=b\neq 0$, and we can represent the row-reduced matrix as
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -4\\ 
0 & b & 0
\end{bmatrix}
Notice what this means in the context of $(2)$:
$$
0x_1+bx_2=0 \Longleftrightarrow x_2=\frac{0}{b}.
$$
This simplifies your work quite a bit, for now you are dealing with the two linear equations $x_1+2x_2=-4$ and $x_2=\frac{0}{b}$. Substitute $x_2=\frac{0}{b}$ into the first linear equation and see what happens:
$$
x_1+2\left(\frac{0}{b}\right)=-4.
$$
With $x_1=-4$ this equation will be true for *any* value of $b=h-10$ or, equivalently, any value of $h$. Thus, your system of linear equations will be consistent regardless of your choice for $h$. That's a pretty dirty explanation, but hopefully it will give you a more intuitive grasp of the situation.

Comment: This clears things up a lot - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the system $Ax = b$ is inconsistent if the augmented matrix $A|b$ has a pivot on the last column. it is because you get an equation of the form $0x = 1.$ in your case the reduced from of the augmented matrix cannot have a pivot in the last column. therefore $Ax = b$ is consistent for any $h.$

Answer (score 0):

If $\;h=10\;$ then the second row is a multiple of the first one and thus the system reduces to

$$x+2y=-4$$

and this  thing *always* has solution.